# How do I access the string in an entry box if its inside a frame (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I access the Entry and its contents when its inside a frame? I tried Entry.get() to print it but it doesnt work, I also tried printing the frame itself but it didnt really work, I want to be able to print out what I write inside the entry box, help is appreciated, thank you!

```
frame8 = Frame(window1, width=500, height=400, bd=1, bg='#474545')
frame8.pack()

iframe9 = Frame(frame, bd=2, relief=RIDGE)
Label(iframe9, text='Fees:').pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
Entry(iframe9, bg='white', fg='#474545').pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
iframe9.pack(expand=1, fill=X, pady=10, padx=5)

def submit():
    print(Entry.get())
frame10 = Frame(window1, width=500, height=400, bd=1, bg='#474545')
frame10.pack()

iframe11 = Button(frame, bd=2, relief=RIDGE, text="Submit", command=submit)
t = StringVar()
iframe11.pack(expand=1, fill=X, pady=10, padx=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the `Entry` object in a variable, just like you did with the frame.  Then, you use `get` on that object.

```
box = Entry(iframe9, bg='white', fg='#474545')
box.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)
...
print(box.get())
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that but I got this error

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Titanium\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 148, in submit
    print(box.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Oh, that's because you stacked commands.  The `pack` function doesn't return its object.  I'll fix.